# Qt installation in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, qt, installation, visual-studio-2019

I have downloaded Qt for open source development and installed it.I installed 5.15.0 version:
[image]

but when I enter VS 2019 Qt vs tool are not added in my main menu:[image]

which is not problematic because I have it in my extentions:

[image]

but  **the problem is**  when I want to create a gui application there is no such thing:

[image]

Any idea what should I do or what should have done which I didn't?

my instructor showed something like this:

[image]

and chose Qt GUI Application, but I don't have that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your picture shows the menu to add stuff to existing project.

To "create a gui application" with Qt in Visual Studio 2019 you will need to create a new project (`File` -> `New` -> `Project`) and here inside the search bar type `qt` that will find the projects templates related to Qt and you'll have `Qt Widgets Application` in there (or `Qt Quick Application` if you want to use QtQuick/qml).

For all this to work you also need to setup Visual Studio's Qt extension to find the Qt framework you installed on your system.
To do that go to Qt Options (`Extensions` -> `Qt VS Tools` -> `Qt Options`) and in  tab `Qt Versions` click `Add` button: here insert something like `Qt5.15.0` for version name and the path where you installed Qt frameworks on your system the default will be: `C:\Qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64`.

Comment: oh you are right thanks. I found what you mentioned ,but my instructor chose Qt GUI Application and I don't have that. (I showed in my edited question) is it OK? and what should I chose instead of it(sorry it's my first experience with Qt)?

Comment: That picture is an older version of both Visual Studio and Qt extension, the "Qt Widgets Application" is what that is called in the current version.